# Calculating gradient from network output in PyTorch gives error

Tags: python, pytorch, loss-function

I am trying to use a manually calculate a gradient using the output of my network, I will then use this in a loss function. I have managed to get an example working in keras, but converting it to PyTorch has proven more difficult

I have a model like:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(1, 50)  
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(50, 10)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(10, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.sigmoid(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.sigmoid(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x
```

and some data:

```
x = torch.unsqueeze(torch.linspace(-1, 1, 101), dim=1)
x = Variable(x)
```

I can then try find a gradient like:

```
output = net(x)
grad = torch.autograd.grad(outputs=output, inputs=x, retain_graph=True)[0]
```

I want to be able to find the gradient of each point, then do something like:

```
err_sqr = (grad - x)**2
loss = torch.mean(err_sqr)**2
```

However, at the moment if I try to do this I get the error:

```
grad can be implicitly created only for scalar outputs
```

I have tried changing the shape of my network output to fix this, but if I change it to much it says its not part of the graph. I can get rid of that error by allowing that, but then it says my gradient is `None`. I've managed to get this working in keras, so I'm confident that its possible here too, I just need a hand!

My questions are:

- Is there a way to "fix" what I have to allow me to calculate the gradient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyTorch expects an upstream gradient in the `grad` call. For usual (scalar) loss functions, the upstream gradient is implicitly assumed to be `1`.

You can do a similar thing by passing `ones` as the upstream gradient:

```py
grad = torch.autograd.grad(outputs=output, inputs=x, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(output), retain_graph=True)[0]
```

Comment: thank you, after setting requires_grad=True in my data, x, this has fixed my problem. It now does not throw an error, but also doesn't converge to the correct result. 
Could having an autograd function inside a loss function interfere with my optimiser? Is there a way to stop the two from talking, if that is an issue?

Comment: @Andrew I am not sure what you wanted to do -- make the gradient of `net(x)` to be the same as `x` itself? Why would that make sense? Anyway that seems like a topic for another question.

Comment: You can use this as a method of solving equations. yeah, ill ask another question, again, thank you for your help!